# How to uppercase the first letter in a sentence in PHP?

Tags: php, text-segmentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I display the first letter as uppercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182641/how-do-i-display-the-first-letter-as-uppercase)
>   [PHP capitalize first letter of first word in a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383471/php-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-word-in-a-sentence)

I want to uppercase the first letter in a sentence and after a period. Can anyone suggest how to do?

For example,

```
//I have the following in a language class.
"%s needs to identify areas of strength and 
weakness. %s sets goals for self-improvement."; 

// in a view
$contone=$this->lang->line($colstr);// e.g get the above string.
//$conttwo=substr($contone, 3);//skip "%s " but this doesnot work when there 
//are more than one %s
$conttwo=str_replace("%s ", "", $contone);// replace %s to none 
$contthree = ucfirst($conttwo); // this only uppercase the first one
```

I want the following output.

```
Needs to identify areas of strength and 
weakness. Sets goals for self-improvement.
```

Comment: Reliably?  Might not be possible.  It would be hard to differentiate between a full stop and a decimal point.  You could explode() the string on the . character, ucfirst each element in the array and implode() the result, or preg_replace for . characters followed by at least one space an an [a-z], but there's plenty of scope for error in either approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try below.

It will run the function to capitalize every letter AFTER a full-stop (period) in a string having multiple sentences.

```
    $string = ucfirst(strtolower($string));     

    $string = preg_replace_callback('/[.!?].*?\w/', create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'),$string);

    echo $string;
```

Please do required changes.

Comment: There is a problem with your solution. If the sentence has proper names cannot be converted to lowercase, then the correction follows:

$string = ucfirst(preg_replace_callback('/,\s[A-Z]/', create_function('$matches', 'return strtolower($matches[0]);'), $string));
$string = preg_replace_callback('/[.]\s([a-z])/', create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'),$string);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
//define string
$string = "your sentences";

//first we make everything lowercase, and then make the first letter if the entire string capitalized
$string = ucfirst(strtolower($string));

//now we run the function to capitalize every letter AFTER a full-stop (period).
$string = preg_replace_callback('/[.!?].*?\w/', create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'),$string);

//print the result
echo $string;

?>
```