# Capitalize the first letter of sentences in paragraphs

Tags: php, wordpress, text-segmentation

I am using WordPress and WP-O-Matic to automatically pull contents from different feeds. The contents are in all caps making the posts in the WordPress blog looks crappy. I tried using different techniques, but none of them seem to work flawlessly.

Here are some examples I tried:
[How to uppercase the first letter in a sentence in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951436/how-to-uppercase-the-first-letter-in-a-sentence-in-php)
[How to capitalize first letter of first word in a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383471/php-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-word-in-a-sentence)

I am currently using this piece of code, but its not working like it should:

```
function fwisc_content($content) {
if ( is_single() ) {
global $post;
$string = get_the_content($post->ID);
$sentences = preg_split('/([.?!]+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$new_string = '';
foreach ($sentences as $key => $sentence) {
    $new_string .= ($key & 1) == 0?
        ucfirst(strtolower(trim($sentence))) :
        $sentence.' ';
}
return trim($new_string); 

} else { 
    return $content;
}
}
add_action( 'the_content', 'fwisc_content' );
```

The problem is this code removes all the `<p></p>` tags making the whole post looks like a single paragraph.

Here is what I need to do:
Sample Input:

```
<p>THIS IS THE FIRST SENTENCE. THIS IS THE SECOND SENTENCE! THIS IS THE THIRD SENTENCE.. THIS IS THE FOURTH SENTENCE! IS THIS THE FIFTH SENTENCE?</p>
<p>THIS IS THE FIRST SENTENCE. THIS IS THE SECOND SENTENCE! THIS IS THE THIRD SENTENCE.. THIS IS THE FOURTH SENTENCE! IS THIS THE FIFTH SENTENCE?</p>
```

Expected Output:

```
<p>This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence! This is the third sentence.. This is the fourth sentence! Is this the fifth sentence?</p>
<p>This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence! This is the third sentence.. This is the fourth sentence! Is this the fifth sentence?</p>
```

Please help

Comment: Can you provide some input and expected output ? Also how is your code removing `<p></p>` ?

Comment: @HamZa Edited my question and added the sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Abhik: There is no `<p></p>` in your given input.

Comment: Sorry, edited again..

Comment: Your [code doesn't remove](https://eval.in/42809) `<p></p>` as I suspected from the beginning. It seems like a troll attempt.

Comment: @HamZa, yes, it shouldn't remove the `<p></p>` tags, but in fact it IS removing them in my local installation. Weird!!

Comment: @Abhik: You need to provide a non-working input for us to investigate.

Comment: @Abhik It's not weird, it's proven. Read the code, function by function and you'll see there is nothing that removes html tags. My wild guess would be that `get_the_content($post->ID)` doesn't return a string with `p` tags.

Comment: Try to debug by using `var_dump(get_the_content($post->ID));`

Comment: @Abhik Have you tried debugging a bit by doing a print_r($sentences) before your foreach loop?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but do the `<p>` tags exist in the first place and not wrapped inside `DIVs` or `<br>` tags?

Comment: A possible solution that could work (mind you I don't know how to do this, but I am pretty good with scenarios), is to setup a function inside checking to see if a `<p>` exists in the first place, and if not, add the appropriate tags (<p></p>) to each post ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following code:

```
<style>
    p:first-letter
    {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
</style>
<?php
function upperFirstWord($str) {
    return preg_replace('/([.!?])\s*(\w)/e', "strtoupper('\\1 \\2')", ucfirst(strtolower($str)));
}

echo upperFirstWord("<p>THIS IS THE FIRST SENTENCE. THIS IS THE SECOND SENTENCE! THIS IS THE THIRD SENTENCE.. THIS IS THE FOURTH SENTENCE! IS THIS THE FIFTH SENTENCE?</p><p>THIS IS THE FIRST SENTENCE. THIS IS THE SECOND SENTENCE! THIS IS THE THIRD SENTENCE.. THIS IS THE FOURTH SENTENCE! IS THIS THE FIFTH SENTENCE?</p>");
?>
```

Hope this will help. Thank you :-)

Comment: [Copy paste](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5383786) and then some edit ? Note that the [`e` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) instead. Next time also please read the comments, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @HamZa It was a noble and commendable attempt ;-) Mind you, it seems rather more simpler just using CSS.

Comment: @Fred I don't mind copy pasting, as long as it's good or corrected. CSS is actually a good solution, let's hope I'm not using telnet to open that page lol

Comment: @HamZa Btw, have you seen my comment in the OP's original question? I'm starting to wonder about that.

Comment: @Fred Yes I did, they don't exist, I assure you :D

Comment: @HamZa That's what I suspected. I'm not a Wordpress guy, but after looking at your `eval`, is when my left brow went up. ;-)

Comment: **Let me rephrase**; "Mind you, it seems rather more simpler just using CSS, **IF** the `<p>` tag(s) EXIST in the first place.